# Unexpected results from SQL "previous" query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to get the previous image from a database in which images are listed by their id numbers. After some research I came across this query which should provide the previous result. However it's not doing so. Instead it's providing the first result that is less than the current id number. (Code is formatted for preparred statement in PDO, please ignore the `:name` variables.)

```
SELECT * FROM `images`
WHERE `category` = :cat
AND `id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `id` = :id)
AND `id` < :id OR `id` < (SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `id` = :id)
ORDER BY `id` 
LIMIT 1
```

Here's an example of what the table looks like.

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | Image     | Category |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 3  | image.png | 3        |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 6  | image.jpg | 3        |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 12 | anim.gif  | 3        |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Now if I was on image 12, this would say that the "previous image" was id 3, instead of id 6.

Comment: `(SELECT \`id\` FROM \`images\` WHERE \`id\` = :id)` – that subquery just makes no sense at all, because it will return the exact value that you put into it for the `:id` placeholder in the first place. And neither does demanding the id be equal to that value first, AND less than the value in the next condition.

Comment: And because of no parentheses, it is only the last part connected with OR that makes this return anything at all (but therefor it does not limit the result to the category any more either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `SELECT id FROM images WHERE id = :id` is a NOOP. Now what you want, is the row with the highest ID less than a given - this should not be too hard:

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE id<:id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: The "DESC" was all that I was missing from my original query. Not sure about this entire query that I posted, looks like a mess, I just found it on an answer in SO